# Call methods from another class. How it works?

Tags: ruby, oop

The method defined in a different class and I don't understand how methods are associated with each other

```
class Route
 attr_reader :stations #getter method
end

class Train
  attr_accessor :route #getter and setter method

  def show_stations
     route.stations # How it works?
  end
end

route = Route.new
train = Train.new

train.route = route
train.show_stations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a method call has an explicit receiver, it doesn't matter in what context you call it from. All that matters is that the receiver has that method.

The context of method call `route.stations` does not matter. All that matters is whether the receiver `route` has the method `stations`. Since `route` is a `Route` instance, it does have the method `stations`, as defined by `attr_reader :stations`.